# Qt how to import language binding

Tags: qt, binding

I can find lots of examples of how to create a language binding for Qt, but not how to import one. I have downloaded a file with bindings for PHP (don't ask) and want to add it to my Qt. Can't find a "how to" for it.

Comment: I am not looking to run out of Qt, more I want an IDE interface and Qt is what I have.

Comment: You can find examples of how to create a language binding? Can you share one? Unsure what it is besides Python Qt and did not see an example of how they created it (I assume somebody worked for many days for that).

Comment: I did a Google for "Qt language Bindings" and among the top is this:  https://wiki.qt.io/Language_Bindings